# Too Many "Is X Vegetarian" Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been a lot of questions on this site regarding "is X vegetarian/sattvic?" (I'm even guilty of writing one myself).

IMO vegetarianism is an important aspect of the Hindu religion, but these questions are getting out of hand. It's unclear if we should consider them off-topic since they are technically about Hinduism, but at the same time we don't want to deal with a new question every day asking about the status of some random food item.

I think we should have one canonical Q&A that explicitly describes the rules of Tamasic, Rajasic, and Sattvic foods and mark all other questions as duplicates of that one.

What are your opinions on this?

**EDIT**

I have created a Q&A wiki on the main site. From now on, please flag other questions on vegetarianism, etc. as duplicates of this one. Also, the answer is community wiki, so feel free to add more info so we can have one canonical answer.

[Link to the Q&A Wiki](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/what-are-tamasic-rajasic-and-sattvic-foods)

Comment: I agree, we should create one Q&A wiki. So that other users can contribute it..

Comment: It is fine to ask general ones, taking each item and asking another question makes no sense, [still users want such questions](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/) so even mods can't help in this

Comment: @Mr.Alien The mods could help by closing such questions as duplicates of the wiki.

Comment: @Akshay And I did if you see, but users reopen. Also, you cannot possibly make a wiki out of this, I do like your idea but again, users just not getting ready to keep the site clean and keep quality posts coming.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Well that's on hold for being off-topic. I meant that they could be marked as duplicates of the wiki, which would theoretically provide the answer to any questions of this sort. And why don't you think it would be possible to have a wiki answer?

Comment: @Akshay because the topic we discuss is wide, users manage to ask a question by changing bits of it due to which you cannot close as a dupe always, also, its off topic now, but due to low rep you cannot see re open votes, system shows me that there are 2 re open votes already...

Comment: @Mr.Alien I somewhat disagree. If we have a wiki that explicitly states what Tamasic, Rajasic, and Sattvic foods are and provides sufficient examples, then any question asking if random food item X is vegetarian can be considered a duplicate of that one. And thanks for clarifying about the reopen votes; you're right, I can't see them yet.

Comment: @Akshay Well, to be honest, am not a pro user to comment over this, hence I keep the site clean when I feel that questions are adding nothing new to the site, but if you really want a wiki post, than it will cover a huge ground. Also, am not sure how big the answer will go, let jabahar or keshav comment over this, if they can write one than you feel free to ask a question, I'll turn the post to community wiki

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of one Q&A, it should be a wiki article, otherwise agree with your question.

Comment: I don't think we can possibly create a wiki article for this, there are tons of food items, it is better to write a generalized post of tamsic food items and whatever is related to that

Comment: That's exactly why it should be a wiki. Wiki can be edited and grow as different users contribute different parts, long after we are gone.

Comment: agree with the wiki idea. let it grow as and when users find questions to every food item

Comment: I don't agree because the question in discussion would then be too broad. And there would be many duplicates to it, since it won't be index-able in search to the level of different questions.